# UILabel padding messed up when it is multi line

Tags: swift, swift4

I subclass UILabel to add top padding and it fixed the vertical position of the label.

[image: Imgur]

The code looks like this:

```swift
class PaddedUILabel: UILabel {
    var topInset: CGFloat = 0
    var rightInset: CGFloat = 0
    var bottomInset: CGFloat = 0
    var leftInset: CGFloat = 0

    public func normalize(top: CGFloat) {
        topInset = top
        drawText(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
    }

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        let insets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: self.topInset, left: self.leftInset, bottom: self.bottomInset, right: self.rightInset)
        self.setNeedsLayout()
        return super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: insets))
    }
}
```

And I call it in `viewDidLoad` using `label.normalize(top: 3)`

However, when the label becomes multiline, the padding messed up (left). It only fixed when I remove the `label.normalize(top: 3)`.

[image: img]

Here's how I'm applying it

```swift
class LocationsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var locationsLabel: PaddedUILabel!
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        locationsLabel.text = nil
    }

    private let paragraphStyle: NSMutableParagraphStyle = {
        let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        style.lineSpacing = 5.0
        style.alignment = .left
        style.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        return style
    }()

    func setupCell(uiModel: LocationsUIModel) {
        locationsLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        switch uiModel {
        case .locations(let text):
//                        let longText = "Another long location that spans into multiple lines. Location location location location location location 123456789"
            let onelineText = "Hyde Park"
            let attrText = onelineText.set(fontStyle(UIFont.geomanistFont(ofSize: UIFont.smallSize)) + colorStyle(.pepper))
            //            let attrText = text.set(fontStyle(UIFont.spFont(ofSize: UIFont.smallSize)) + colorStyle(.pepper))
            attrText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attrText.length))
            locationsLabel.attributedText = attrText
        //            locationsLabel.normalize(top: 3)
        default:
            break
        }

    }
}
```

The expected result will be to show all 3 lines and still maintain the correctness of single line

Comment: Why not just set the `gravity` to centre if you want the text centred?

Comment: @AngryDuck what do you mean by gravity?

Comment: i think @AngryDuck meant the textAlignment property https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620541-textalignment

Comment: @SebastianWeiß it's more on the vertical rather than horizontal text alignment